# How is it possible to dynamically change the flash file using swfobject through javascript

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I'm looking to dynamically change the flash files based from an hyperlink on the page without the page having to reloading. Is this possible through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See this tutorial:
http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/load-a-swf-using-javascript-onclick-event/

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to change the destination of a hyperlink on the page through javascript?  Something like this should do that:

```
<body>
    <a id="test" href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('test').href = 'http://www.yahoo.com'" value="Go to Yahoo"/>
</body>
```

Or are you trying to do something different?  Like changing what Flash is displayed by clicking a hyperlink?  Haven't tried it, but the above approach might work there, too, with a little tweaking.  Remember that the attributes of an element (like the href above) are available in javascript as properties once you have a reference to the element, so you should be able to change whatever attribute of the element you need to.